# WCF Service works in debug but not as Windows Service

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding, self-hosting

I have a WCF service that is a self hosted Windows Service. When debugging with the WCF Test Client the service works great. I use Javascript with simple ajax requests that return JSON. Although when I run the service as a Windows Service the request get a 400 error. I'm guessing this may have something to do with my config.

Any help is appreciated.

**WCF Test Client Config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="MetadataExchangeHttpBinding_ISkyMobileService">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8523/HLT/Sky/SkyMobileService/mex"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MetadataExchangeHttpBinding_ISkyMobileService"
            contract="ISkyMobileService" name="MetadataExchangeHttpBinding_ISkyMobileService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Windows Service App.Config**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="HLT.Sky.MobileDeviceServices.SkyMobileService" behaviorConfiguration="HeliosMobileServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8523/HLT/Sky/SkyMobileService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="HLT.Sky.MobileDeviceServices.ISkyMobileService" bindingNamespace="http://HLT.Sky.MobileDeviceServices" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="HLT.Sky.MobileDeviceServices.ISkyMobileService" bindingNamespace="http://HLT.Sky.MobileDeviceServices" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SkyMobileServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Windows Service Implementation**

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.ServiceModel;


namespace HLT.Sky.WindowsService1
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        internal static ServiceHost myServiceHost = null;

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if (myServiceHost != null)
            {
                myServiceHost.Close();
            }
            myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MobileDeviceServices.SkyMobileService));
            myServiceHost.Open();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (myServiceHost != null)
            {
                myServiceHost.Close();
                myServiceHost = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**WCF Interface**

```
    #region GET
    // Return JSON Store for specified chartType
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetChartData?chartType={chartType}&serialNumber={serialNumber}&_dc={dc}&limit={limit}&callback={callback}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetChartData(string dc, string limit, string callback, int chartType, string serialNumber);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetHomePageData();
    #endregion

    #region POST
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "VerifyPINData?pinData={pinData}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    bool VerifyPINData(string pinData);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "SubmitCNPData?cnpData={cnpData}&serialNumber={serialNumber}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    bool SubmitCNPData(int cnpData, string serialNumber);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "SendEmail?mailTo={mailTo}&subject={subject}&message={message}",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    bool SendEmail(string mailTo, string subject, string message);

    #endregion
```

**Program.cs**

```
static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new Service1() 
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
```

Comment: can you describe how you got your wcf to run in windows services. you have to implement the start method in the windows service class and turn you self hosted wcf there

Comment: Try to troubleshoot using Fidler.

Comment: Also try to host in IIS instead of self-hosting windows service.

Comment: @abatishchev Due to the situation I need the WCF to be self hosted as a Windows Service.

Comment: This way you can make sure that it's all fine with service itself and the issue caused by self-hosting.

Comment: Please post more code. Classes' signatures and Program.cs content.

Comment: Include please windows service class full implementation including signature (namespace, base class, etc.)

Comment: @abatishchev the latest edits pretty much finish up the service. The only additional thing is the project installer.

Comment: btw `includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"` is extremely helpful for troubleshooting, specially on the first stage.

Comment: And still try [Fidler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to debug JSON output. Also try to host the same configuration on local/remote IIS, just to test.

Comment: @abatishchev I'll try setting it up on IIS. The GET request to the web service doesn't return any JSON to debug.

Comment: Are you sure the service is starting successfully? I suspect that myServiceHost.Open() is throwing... for example if the service account does not have permissions to open a port. A standard user will not have that granted by default.

Comment: @ErnieL Yes, I can get to the root information page (http://localhost:8523/HLT/Sky/SkyMobileService). Netstat shows the port is listening as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an endpoint behavior and removing the "mex" endpoint ended up fixing the problem. See working config file below:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="HLT.Sky.MobileDeviceServices.ISkyMobileService" />
    </client>
    <services>
      <service name="HLT.Sky.MobileDeviceServices.SkyMobileService" behaviorConfiguration="SkyMobileServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8523/HLT/Sky/SkyMobileService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="HLT.Sky.MobileDeviceServices.ISkyMobileService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SkyMobileServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: It's nice you solved this, but you say: _"Although when I run the service as a Windows Service the request get a 400 error. I'm guessing"_. You shouldn't be guessing, you should look up the error and fix that. Without a mex endpoint, you'll have to fall back to WSDL and that is not always the ideal option.

Comment: @CodeCaster Good point. I know it has to do with my config now. I just know when I add the mex endpoint I get a HTTP status of 200, but no data is returned. When I remove it then I get data. I'm not entirely sure why this is.